# Regular expression with first character in latin is not working. Why?

Tags: javascript, regex, text

I have a text where I would like to find different words. The following text is in Portuguese, Brazil, and serves only as a test case:

```
Um dia eu conheci Pedro Álvares Cabral, e descobri muitas informações interessantes.
```

To find any of the words in the text, I am using the following regular expression:

```
/\b(Cabral)\b/i // Finds Cabral
/\b(dia)\b/i    // Finds dia
/\b(Pedro)\b/i  // Finds Pedro
Etc...
```

If I need to find more than one word, I do as follows:

```
/\b(informações|muitas)\b/ig
```

I am testing the functionality of the expression in both JavaScript and using [this online utility](https://www.regextester.com/). JavaScript code example:

```js
var input = "Um dia eu conheci Pedro Álvares Cabral, e descobri muitas informações interessantes."
var matchRegExp = new RegExp("\\b(coNHECi)\\b", "i");

if(regs = matchRegExp.exec(input)) {
  console.log('OK');
}
else {
  console.log('NOPE');
}
```

### THE PROBLEM

All the words I put into the expression are found, except `Álvares`. For example, I cannot find the word with the following expression:

```
/\b(Álvares)\b/i
```

If I remove the `Á` character, `lvares` is found. I would like to:

1. To know why and for what reason I can't find `Álvares`.
2. To know how I can find any word in a text that has the following
   characters: áàâãÁÀÂÃéèêÉÈÊíìîÍÌÎóòôõÓÒÔÕúùûÚÙÛñÑçÇ regardless of whether these characters represent the first, last, or any letter of a word.

Comment: I think it's the `\b` that's causing the problem. I suspect that it does not properly treat the accented "A" as being a "word" character.

Comment: JavaScript regex support for Unicode is pretty sad.